# POST data with cURL via TOR

Tags: php, curl, tor

I'm trying to post data via TOR using cURL and PHP code below

```
$url = "http://www.example.com";
$data = "test=true&entry_id=123";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But somehow when I check access log I do not see that activity. When I use code below (just accessing the site, no posting data) activity appears in the log

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Any clue what can be wrong with the first chunk of the code?

Comment: Regarding the first POST request, what does `var_dump($response); var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` show?

Comment: Looks like a PHP problem. Switched to PERL and all is working fine